# What is wrong with my Razor syntax?

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I have made one file named `twitter.cshtml`. In that page my code looks like:

```
@if (Request["TwitterUser"].IsEmpty())
{
    @Twitter.Search("microsoft")
}
else
{
    @Twitter.Profile(Request["TwitterUser"])
}
```

I got an error that Twitter is found in line - `@Twitter.Profile(Request["TwitterUser"])`.

Why is this?

Comment: Is this in WebMatrix? Do you use MVC 3?

Comment: you should change your title to something more meaningful to the problem

Comment: You need to include more detail. What is the error? Can you show us the Twitter.Profile method? Is it in a namespace that is included?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @ signs inside the if and else blocks.

```
@if (Request["TwitterUser"].IsEmpty())
{
    Twitter.Search("microsoft")
}
else
{
    Twitter.Profile(Request["TwitterUser"])
}
```

You only need to use the @ sign when you are inside of markup, not when you are inside of code blocks (like if statements).

```
@if (Request["TwitterUser"].IsEmpty())
{
    <div>@Twitter.Search("microsoft")</div>
}
else
{
    <text>@Twitter.Profile(Request["TwitterUser"])</text>
}
```

In the if block, the call to Twitter.Search() is now inside an HTML tag (markup), so you need to use the @ sign.  In the else loop, the `<text>` tag will not be rendered, it's a special tag that is just there to tell Razor to go into markup mode.

Comment: If you use @Whatever.Something() inside a codeblock, that will output the result of the method to the page. Tehnically what he did wasn't incorrect, though it's hard to determine exactly what result he's expecting.